# Removing Pudb on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pudb

While ago I made a mistake and installed pudb without precisely installing it in a specific anaconda environment. Now I am trying to find it and remove it.

When I run :

```
pudb3 file_name.py
```

the debugger appears (no matter if I am in the (base) environment or any other conda environment).

Now I want to remove it in order to install a fresh instance of pudb inside my prefered conda environment. But I ca not.

When I do :

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove python-pudb
```

It returnes:

```
E: Unable to locate package python-pudb
```

When I do :

```
apt-cache policy python-pudb
```

It returns:

```
N: Unable to locate package python-pudb
```

I would appreciate any help.

- Ubuntu: 22.04
- Python(base): 3.9.13
- PuDB: PUDB 2020.1

Comment: I don't know if this is a good fit to this site, maybe it is a better fit to https://unix.stackexchange.com/? Just a thought.